# Win32 GDI Brush object

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, gdi

I am going through Microsoft's "Get started with Win32" chain of articles and not far in I've stumbled on this line `FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1));`

As far as I understand the `(HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1)` cast essentially makes the `COLOR_WINDOW+1` the address stored in the resulting `HBRUSH` pointer and I don't quite understand what is it trying to achieve. Going further I've looked how the `HBRUSH` struct is defined inside the `windef.h` header, which is a macro resulting in this definition:

```
struct HBRUSH__{int unused;}; typedef struct HBRUSH__ *HBRUSH
```

and there are many other structs defined the same way. Next step was checking what function like for example `CreateSolidBrush(RGB(100,100,100))` returns and inspect via Visual Studio debugger what is being stored inside this struct. The result of the function was a pointer to a struct which `int unused` field was, well, unused. So what is the point of having a structure with unused fields like defined above? If I had to guess it is a way of unification, a way to safeguard casting one struct to another, but unused field still doesn't really make sense to me.

But really main points of confusion to me are: what is the point of casting `color` described as `integer` to `HBRUSH` thus making it the address of the resulting pointer? Where the RGB color of Brush is being stored? And I guess unlimately how is `HBRUSH` being handled by functions like `FillRect()` and `CreateSolibBrush` internally, at least approximately?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140305-00/?p=1593

Comment: `(HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1)` is not a real brush handle. `FillRect` has special logic to recognize small numerical values as indexes that can be passed to `GetSysColor`.

Comment: A handle is not meant to be a pointer to any particular structure. The reason it's declared the way you show is for type safety, so the compiler can detect and complain if you try to pass, say, `HDC` where `HBRUSH` is expected. At the end of the day, it's just a numerical value that has some meaning to the software component that produced it in the first place. The calling code is not supposed to make sense of it, just to pass it back to that component. Just like, say, a phone number is a meaningless sequence of digits used to identify a particular phone plan subscriber.

Comment: IMHO you should skip trying to understand GDI/GDI+, you only need very small bits of it and move to the next articles about the more modern Direct2D https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/overview-of-the-windows-graphics-architecture and/or WinUI3. All this is weird from a current point of view because for legacy reasons, it's very old (I can say that because I'm a much older programmer :-)

Comment: I wish the link was posted **with** the title: [Why do I have to add 1 to the color index when I set it as the hbrBackground of a window class?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140305-00/?p=1593)

Comment: Unrelated or related: Get rid of GDI. Use Direct2D.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to specify a brush:  by a GDI handle or by one of the standard color numbers.  Since C functions cannot be overloaded, FillRect and many other WinAPI functions resort to "type punning" to smuggle different types of arguments into a parameter.

The common way to refer to a GDI brush is by its handle.  When a brush is created, GDI assigns it an identifier.  Maybe that's just a number.  Instead of returning that identifier as an integer, GDI dresses it up as an HBRUSH.

The fact that an HBRUSH is a pointer is just an implementation trick to help the compiler give you warnings when you try to pass the wrong type of handle.  It is not a pointer to the object owned by GDI, it's just a way to refer to it.  In fact, it's likely it's not even a valid pointer at all.

When you pass an HBRUSH into a GDI function, it turns it back into the identifier and uses that as a key to find the actual brush object.

Instead of making each client create all of its own brushes, some GDI APIs allow you to reference a solid brush of one of the system colors by number, like COLOR_WINDOW or COLOR_TEXT, etc.

But those are just integers, and you cannot pass an integer to a function expecting an HBRUSH, so you have to cast it.  Casting it is a lie to the compiler:  You're saying pretend this number is actually an HBRUSH.  The function I'm calling will know what I mean.

There's an extra wrinkle.  Since the HBRUSH is actually a pointer under the hood, if you try to cast 0 to an HBRUSH, the result is a null pointer.  The handle system assumes null a pointer means "no object."  That causes a problem because one of the system colors is COLOR_SCROLLBAR, whose index is 0.

To avoid the conflict, GDI expects you to add one to the index of a system color index before you cast it to an HBRUSH.

The IDs are arranged such that `(HBRUSH)(color_index + 1)` won't conflict with a brush you make from a function like CreateBrush.

If you find this casting distasteful, you can specify an HBRUSH by calling `GetSysColorBrush` like this:

```c
FillRect(hdc, &ps.rcPaint, GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW));
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's address these:

> But really main points of confusion to me are:
>
> 1. What is the point of casting color described as integer to HBRUSH thus making it the address of the resulting pointer?
> 2. Where the RGB color of Brush is being stored?
> 3. How is HBRUSH being handled by functions like FillRect() and CreateSolidBrush internally, at least approximately?

So:

#1 provides a convenient way to draw using the system colours without having to create a brush of your own.  It's also efficient, because, again, you don't have the overhead of creating a brush just for that.

#2 In some kind of table inside GDI.  Ultimately, apart from the special cases covered by #1, an `HBRUSH` acts as an index into said table and that's where the RGB values are stored.  There are also pattern brushes, which can be of arbitrary size, and none of that information will fit in the `HBRUSH` struct itself.  That's just for type-safety, as @igor points out.

#3: (pseudo code)

```
if (brush value is small)*
    assume it's one of the predefined SYSCOLOR brushes
else
    look it up in the table of brushes stored inside GDI and do funky stuff

* i.e. if ((uint_ptr) my_brush < 32), or whatever
```

And, needless to say, when you create a brush it is added to the table and when you destroy it it is removed.  Questions welcome, put them in the comments.

Comment: So I get the #1 and #2 explanation. What I'm trying to wrap my head around is that in #3 example the brush value in if statement is actually an address. Maybe it's just my lack of knowledge and experience with C and I wasn't given a chance to deal with addresses this way specifically. Or maybe I'm just trying to find deeper meaning where the answer is pretty straight forward.

Comment: That's the whole point.  An `HBRUSH` is *never* an address, it's just dressed up to look like one for type safety.  Added a brief not to my answer to show how you can treat as `HBRUSH` as an integer.